# create a new column based on string of another column

Tags: python, string, function

I have dataframe with COLUMN A as below, and I want to create a new column called as "complexity based on column A. However the output doesn't reflect my desired output. Can someone help?

```
   A
dev DH
dev DHGP
dev SEA
dev MONO
dev SLIM DH
dev SLIM MONO
```

```
def complexity_column(df,classes):
    conditions_region = [
    (df[classes].str.contains("DH")),
    (df[classes].str.contains("DHGP")),
    (df[classes].str.contains("SEA")),
    (df[classes].str.contains("MONO")),
    (df[classes].str.contains("SLIM DH")),
    (df[classes].str.contains("SLIM MONO"))
    
    ]

    # create a list of the values we want to assign for each condition
    values_regions = ['DH','CHGP', 'SEA','MONO','SLIM DH','SLIM MONO']

    # create a new column and use np.select to assign values to it using our lists as arguments
    df['COMPLEXITY'] = np.select(conditions_region, values_regions)
    return df
```

output

```
complexity_column(df,"A")
output:
   A              COMPLEXITY
dev DH               DH
dev DHGP             DH
dev SEA              SEA
dev MONO             MONO
dev SLIM DH          DH
dev SLIM MONO        MONO
```

and my desire output is as below

```
   A              COMPLEXITY
dev DH               DH
dev DHGP             DHGP
dev SEA              SEA
dev MONO             MONO
dev SLIM DH          SLIM DH
dev SLIM MONO        SLIM MONO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [numpy.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html): `numpy.select(condlist, choicelist, default=0)`

> condlist: The list of conditions which determine from which array in choicelist the output elements are taken. When multiple conditions are satisfied, **the first one encountered in condlist is used**.

You need to reorder the elements in `conditions_region` to make sure that the more specific conditions appear first and general conditions appear last.

That is,

```py
conditions_region = [
    df[classes].str.contains("SLIM DH"),
    df[classes].str.contains("SLIM MONO"),
    df[classes].str.contains("DHGP"),
    df[classes].str.contains("DH"),
    df[classes].str.contains("SEA"),
    df[classes].str.contains("MONO")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using .str.contains which takes a subset of the string why not just use **==**, i.e.:

```
def complexity_column(df,classes):
    conditions_region = [
    (df[classes] == "DH"),
    (df[classes] == "DHGP")),
    (df[classes] == "SEA")),
    (df[classes] == "MONO")),
    (df[classes] == "SLIM DH")),
    (df[classes] == "SLIM MONO"))
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def column_maker(entry_row,list_of_strings):
    output_string = ''
    for i in list_of_strings:
        if i in entry_row:
            output_string = output_string +" "+i
    
    return output_string
```

df['complexity'] = df[column_name].apply(lambda x:column_maker(x,list_of_strings))